# What are the differences between the multiple ways to create zero-sized structs?

Tags: struct, rust, encapsulation, unit-type

I found four different ways to create a `struct` with no data:

- ```
  struct A{} // empty struct / empty braced struct
  ```
- ```
  struct B(); // empty tuple struct
  ```
- ```
  struct C(()); // unit-valued tuple struct
  ```
- ```
  struct D; // unit struct
  ```

(I'm leaving arbitrarily nested tuples that contain only `()`s and single-variant `enum` declarations out of the question, as I understand why those shouldn't be used).

**What are the differences** between these four declarations? Would I use them for specific purposes, or are they interchangeable?

The book and the reference were surprisingly unhelpful. I did find [this accepted RFC (*clarified_adt_kinds*)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1506-adt-kinds.md) which goes into the differences a bit, namely that the unit struct also declares a constant value `D` and that the tuple structs also declare constructors `B()` and `C(_: ())`. However it doesn't offer a design guideline on why to use which.

My guess would be that when I export them with `pub`, there are differences in which kinds can actually be constructed outside of my module, but I found no conclusive documentation about that.

Comment: There is no mention of unit type preferences in the [Rust API guidelines](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/). I'm afraid that there is no objective answer to this. :-( You may wish to send this over to users.rust-lang.org or similar venues.

Comment: @E_net4 So you are saying that there is no difference, and it comes down to preference? (In that case, unit structs having dedicated syntax for this purpose makes `D` the most obvious choice)

Comment: I am implying that it's mostly case dependant. The most obvious choice isn't always the best one. Composition of unit values also make a unit value. It also depends on whether creating them from outside the crate is allowed in your public API.

Comment: @E_net4 That sounds like an answer if some of them allow creating values from outside the crate and others don't. That's exactly the part I couldn't figure out.

Comment: You ask two questions: "What are the differences?" and "When would I use them?" One of these is on-topic on SO; the other is not. If you stick to the on-topic one, you'll probably get an answer.

Comment: @trentcl I didn't mean to ask "*Which should I prefer if there are no differences?*", sorry - that's clearly offtopic indeed. Edited. Assuming there are differences, I was looking for the scenarios where those differences matter. I hope it's not considered too broad.

Comment: I can think of a few more cases off the top of my head. `struct A { _marker: PhantomData }` is also a zero-sized struct, `struct A<T> { t: T }` is a zero-sized struct if `T` is zero-sized, `enum A {}` (a no-variant `enum`) is also zero-sized, ...

Comment: @MatthieuM. `PhantomData` has a clear purpose, I know when to use that. A no-variant enum is like `!` (void) not `()` (unit), no value can exist at all.

Comment: @Bergi: Good point on the no-variant :)

Comment: since "unit type" is just a tuple with no fields, shouldn't the "unit struct" be rather `struct E();` than `struct E;` ? That would make more sense.

Comment: @hvertous [The reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/structs.html) calls `struct E;` a "*unit-like struct*".

Comment: @Bergi yes, I know, I was wondering why is that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are only two functional differences between these four definitions (and a fifth possibility I'll mention in a minute):

1. Syntax (the most obvious). [mcarton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50170328/3650362) goes into more detail.
2. When the struct is marked `pub`, whether its [constructor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/constructors.html) (also called [`struct` literal syntax](http://words.steveklabnik.com/structure-literals-vs-constructors-in-rust)) is usable outside the module it's defined in.

The only one of your examples that is not directly constructible from outside the current module is `C`. If you try to do this, you will get an error:

```
mod stuff {
    pub struct C(());
}
let _c = stuff::C(());  // error[E0603]: tuple struct `C` is private
```

This happens because the field is not marked `pub`; if you declare `C` as `pub struct C(pub ())`, the error goes away.

There's another possibility you didn't mention that gives a marginally more descriptive error message: a normal struct, with a zero-sized non-`pub` member.

```
mod stuff {
    pub struct E {
        _dummy: (),
    }
}
let _e = stuff::E { _dummy: () };  // error[E0451]: field `_dummy` of struct `main::stuff::E` is private
```

(Again, you can make the `_dummy` field available outside of the module by declaring it with `pub`.)

Since `E`'s constructor is only usable inside the `stuff` module, `stuff` has exclusive control over when and how values of `E` are created. Many structs in the standard library take advantage of this, like `Box` (to take an obvious example). Zero-sized types work in exactly the same way; in fact, from outside the module it's defined in, the only way you would know that an opaque type is zero-sized is by calling [`mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html).

### See also

- [What is an idiomatic way to create a zero-sized struct that can't be instantiated outside its crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64651511/3650362)
- [Why define a struct with single private field of unit type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63338208/3650362)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I was looking for. Is there any way to make the constructor of a struct public?

Comment: It makes sense that a `Box` should not be manually constructed, because it needs to place data on the heap. But what is a practical use case of a public zero-sized struct with private constructor?

Comment: @kazemakase I knew someone would ask, but I didn't have a use case in mind. The book suggests [using such structs as pointer targets in FFI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ffi.html) (although they use `[u8; 0]` instead of `()` for unclear reasons). I can also imagine using a struct like this to control access to a global resource, through some combination of compile time and runtime enforcement... something like `lazy_static` does but with extra requirements. Maybe you can think of something better?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, by marking all its members `pub`. I have added this information to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
struct D; // unit struct
```

This is the usual way for people to write a zero-sized `struct`.

```
struct A{} // empty struct / empty braced struct
struct B(); // empty tuple struct
```

These are just special cases of basic `struct` and tuple `struct` which happen to have no parameters. [RFC 1506](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1506-adt-kinds.md) explains the rational to allow those (they didn't used to):

> Permit tuple structs and tuple variants with 0 fields. This restriction is artificial and can be lifted trivially. Macro writers dealing with tuple structs/variants will be happy to get rid of this one special case.

As such, they could easily be generated by macros, but people will rarely write those on their own.

```
struct C(()); // unit-valued tuple struct
```

This is another special case of tuple `struct`. In Rust, `()` is a type just like any other type, so `struct C(());` isn't much different from `struct E(u32);`. While the type itself isn't very useful, forbidding it would make yet another special case that would need to be handled in macros or generics (`struct F<T>(T)` can of course be instantiated as `F<()>`).

Note that there are many other ways to have empty types in Rust. Eg. it is possible to have a function return `Result<(), !>` to indicate that it doesn't produce a value, and cannot fail. While you might think that returning `()` in that case would be better, you might *have* to do that if you implement a trait that dictates you to return `Result<T, E>` but lets you choose `T = ()` and `E = !`.

Comment: So most of these exist just because generic code could end up with them, not because they have different functionality? I guess I was confused because [here](https://github.com/DoumanAsh/stm32l4x6_hal/blob/19f6233ef04e549825a3851e25e5829c253a5149/src/rcc/mod.rs#L65) `struct C(());` was used directly while [in other places](https://github.com/DoumanAsh/stm32l4x6_hal/blob/19f6233ef04e549825a3851e25e5829c253a5149/src/gpio/mod.rs#L17-L68) in the same codebase `struct A;` was used.

Comment: @trentcl provides another nice use case in his answer.