# Why define a struct with single private field of unit type?

Tags: rust

Why does [`ParseBoolError`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/library/core/src/str/mod.rs#L149-L151) have the `_priv` field:

```
pub struct ParseBoolError {
    _priv: (),
}
```

I don't think that the `_priv` field is used.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't create an instance of a struct if it has private fields. This is just a trick to prevent `ParseBoolError` from being constructed in user code.

One reason to do this is for forwards compatibility. If users could create it with:

```
let error = ParseBoolError {};
```

then a future version of `ParseBoolError` couldn't add fields without breaking that code.

Comment: There's now an attribute that does this as well: [`#[non_exhaustive]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/type_system.html#the-non_exhaustive-attribute). The `non_exhaustive` attribute prevents any other crate from creating an instance of your struct, on the basis that it may change in the future. On enums, it requires you to always specify `_` in `match` statements.

Comment: @Dev Doesn't sound that good to me... basically you force people to use `_`, now when they upgade library they do not get any warning yet their code will not handle sensibly the new constructors... not terribly useful.

Comment: @Bakuriu It's useful for structs