# What is an idiomatic way to create a zero-sized struct that can't be instantiated outside its crate?

Tags: rust, idioms

I have something similar to this:

```rust
mod private {
    // My crate
    pub struct A;
    
    impl A {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self
        }
        // ...
    }
}

fn main() {
    // External code
    let obj = private::A::new();
    let obj2 = private::A;
}
```

Currently, `A` doesn't need to store any internal state to do what I want it to (it's just being used as a placeholder in an enum), so I made it a zero-sized struct. However, that might change in the future, so I want to prevent code outside this crate from instantiating `A` without going through `A::new()` (i.e. the instantiation of `obj2` in `main()` as it stands should fail).

Essentially, I want the same effect as if I'd added a private field to `A`, but I want it to remain zero-sized.

Currently, I'm thinking about something like this:

```
pub struct A {
    empty: (),
}
```

Or this:

```
pub struct A(());
```

However, I'm not sure which way is most idiomatic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no established idiom for this. I'd use the tuple struct version:

```rust
pub struct A(());
```

Since the field is private, no one outside that module can construct `A`.

This is used [inside the standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/library/std/src/sys/unix/stdio.rs#L5-L7):

```rust
pub struct Stdin(());
pub struct Stdout(());
pub struct Stderr(());
```

The standard library [*also* uses the named field version](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/library/std/src/io/util.rs#L79-L81):

```rust
pub struct Empty {
    _priv: (),
}
```

You could use any zero-sized type (e.g. a zero-length array or [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html)), but `()` is the simplest.

See also:

- [Why define a struct with single private field of unit type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63338208/155423)
- [What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423)
- [What are the differences between the multiple ways to create zero-sized structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50162597/155423)